# Isolated temporary files in Nix derivation

Tags: nix, nixos, nixpkgs

I haven't found any info about handling temporary files in Nix derivations.

I found `$TMP` and `$TMPDIR` env vars, but they both point just to `/tmp`, which is system global.

```
{
  pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
}:
  pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
    pname = "show-tmp"
    version = "0.1.0";
    src = ./.;
    configurePhase = ''
      echo "tmp = $tmp; TMP =  $TMP; TMPDIR = $TMPDIR"
    '';
    buildPhase = '':'';
    installPhase = '':'';        
  }
```

Variable `$tmp` is not defined inside mkDerivation. I would expect such thing, because other derivation scope vars follow low case style such as `$out`.

The problem with /tmp is obvious - it is global directory.
I need to worry about collisions and cleaning.

My derivation-hook archives a big folder tree.

Comment: Typically, anything written to `/tmp` is going to use something like `mktemp`, which  is going to handle creating unique file names for you. You aren't just creating `$TMP/foo` and hoping for the best.

Comment: `/tmp` _was_ global 20 years ago, when Linux didn't support filesystem namespaces. It's only global today if you and your distro are sloppy about defensive configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Linux, don't worry. The Nix sandbox will give your build its own empty `/tmp`. It is removed when your derivation is done.

On macOS, `$TMP` and `$TMPDIR` are taken care of but `/tmp` is a potential problem.

[How Nix creates a private /tmp on Linux](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/340f831ebe9d74659b84667b96251b7ab0edd09d/src/libstore/build/local-derivation-goal.cc#L609-L614)

---

macOS Darwin, where Nix was installed in early 2020:

```
nix-build --expr 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; runCommand "hi" {} "echo a > /tmp/a; ls -al /tmp; sleep 1;"'
ls -al /private/tmp/
...
-rw-r--r--  1 nixbld1  wheel    2 May 19 12:49 a
...
```